# Retrieving the latest record using group

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

```
table(ms_replies)  
|------------------------------------------|
| id | ticketID |  replyStamp              |
|------------------------------------------|
| 1  |  7       | Tue 11 Oct 2011, 8:56am  |
| 2  |  7       | Wed 12 Oct 2011, 9:20am  |
| 3  |  8       | Wed 12 Oct 2011, 16:24pm |
| 4  |  7       | Thu 27 Oct 2011, 20:28pm |
| 5  |  8       | Tue 18 Oct 2011, 9:54am  |
|------------------------------------------|
```

The code I have thus far is:

```
SELECT 
    ticketID,
    MAX(replace(replace(replyStamp, 'pm',''), 'am','')) AS time
FROM 
    ms_replies 
WHERE 
    `ticketID` IN ($IDs)
GROUP BY 
    ticketID
```

But this doesn't return the most recent entry.

Please note the `replace` in the query is necesary to remove the am | pm , this is not my doing, but I cannot chage it, unfortunatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your strings into dates if you want to compare them as dates:

```
SELECT ticketID,
         MAX(STR_TO_DATE(
           REPLACE(REPLACE(replyStamp, 'am', ''), 'pm', ''), 
           '%a %d %b %Y, %T')) AS max_time
    FROM ms_replies 
   WHERE ticketID IN (7, 8)
GROUP BY ticketID;
```

But it's actually not required if the latest entry always have the max id (as in your sample); then you can just check MAX(id) instead, like in @ZaneBien answer - or here:

```
SELECT m.ticketID, m.replyStamp
  FROM ms_replies AS m
 WHERE m.id = (
         SELECT MAX(id) FROM ms_replies 
         WHERE ticketID = m.ticketID
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think group will take the first record when it reduces them down by ticketID (as you have found out) try ordering them by ticketID DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT a.ticketID, a.replyStamp
FROM ms_replies a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM ms_replies
    WHERE ticketID IN ($IDs)
    GROUP BY ticketID
) b ON a.ticketID = b.maxid
```

By the way, you should really have the `replyStamp` column be a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` type instead of a string. That way, you can make all kinds of date/time calculations on it.